# Find b given x and a where a ^ b = x

Tags: bitwise-operators, boolean-operations

Given the result of an XOR operation and one of the operands involved in said operation, how can I go about finding the other operand? Specifically, given the knowledge that `x = a ^ b` and the value of `x` and `a`, how can I find `b`?

Comment: This is a question about boolean logic, not about Python. What did you try yourself? Did you write a Python script that tries to solve it and ran into a specific problem?

Comment: If you know x and a for x = a^b, can't you use logarithms? - log(x)/log(a) or log base a of x

Comment: @kenntnisse: `^` is not exponentiation in this context, it's exclusive-or.

Answer (score 1):

We have that:

```py
x = a ^ b
==> x ^ a = a ^ b ^ a
==> x ^ a = (a ^ a) ^ b
==> x ^ a = 0 ^ b
==> x ^ a = b
```

So, to recover `b`, you can do:

```py
x ^ a
```